# Illegal import meteor parse error using react

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have just installed **node 6** and **react 1.3** but all import es6 imports/exports not working. I'm getting the following error:

> Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration. unexpected token for
>   import and export of jsx files in my app.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: thanks for the code format guys. anyone have the answer to this error?

Comment: If you have an error in your code, please always include the code itself.